# Spring RestController url for findById and findByIds

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

In my Spring Boot application I have a following REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1.0/decisions")
public class CriterionController {

    @Autowired
    private CriterionService criterionService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}/criteria/{criterionId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public CriterionResponse findById(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId, @PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long criterionId) {
        Criterion criterion = criterionService.findById(criterionId);
        return new CriterionResponse(criterion);
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine and I'm able to retrieve `Criterion` by its `ID`.

Right now I need to add additional logic to my `CriterionController` that will retrieve `Criterion` by a set of `IDs`.

Right now I'm in doubt how it can be implemented.. For example should I add a separated endpoint something like:

```
/{decisionId}/criteria/{criterionIds}
```

or for example reuse existing one for this purpose or in some other way. Please advise how to implement it according to a best practice of REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question, but there are 2 options I can suggest:

```
/{decisionId}/criteria?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

or

```
/{decisionId}/criteria?id=1,2,3
```

The former could be seen as more RESTful but can end up with a very long URL since you'll be specifying the query parameter each time.

The latter aggregates the ids in a comma separated list. I personally prefer this option and would go for this.

Although not about REST, both URLs are accepted in Section 3.2.8 of [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.8)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How it will correlate with an existing endpoint path ?

Comment: You can have one endpoint which accepts a List<String> and according to how many you have in your List, return the appropriate results

Comment: One other thing, since I realised you were using a path variable. You can use /{decisionId}/criteria/1,2,3 and store it in a List<String> as well :)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a way to go!